# Batch APPEND (RENAME) a specific keyword to set of files

Tags: macos, shell, batch, python, applescript

I have few files namely - "a", "b", "c",etc.. I want to add the keyword: "**.mov**" to all files in that folder.

Please suggest me an approach which script will be best suited for this - AppleScript, Shell, Python etc. (I being a non-scripting guy).

***Note: I m using MacOSX-Maverics[Terminal].***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ought to work:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in *; do
  mv "$i" "$i.mov"
done
```

Put that in the directory above the directory with your files. Use `chmod +x script.sh`, then from within the directory with your files, `../script.sh`.

EDIT: This assumes your 'set' of files is every file in that directory. If it isn't, you'll need to more clearly define your set.